# Understanding Currying Implemention in Scala

Tags: scala, currying

As an exercise for functional programing in Scala, we have to create a function which currifies. I couldn't create this one so I looked the solution:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) =
  a => b => f(a, b)
```

I looked at it, have been able to play a little with it, but I don't completely understand it.

Could you explain it to me in details ? Where do the little variables `a` and `b` come from ? What is the meaning of `=>` in `a => b` ?

Comment: By "curryfication" you probably mean currying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`curry` is a [Higher Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (method, in Scala terms) which takes a single argument, `f`. `f` itself is a function, which takes two arguments of type `A` and `B` and returns a result of type `C`. The methods (`curry`) return type is also a function of type `Function1[A, Function1[B, C]]`.

> Where do the little variables a and b come from

The parameters `a` and `b` are two values which are passed to `f`. `a` is of type `A` and b is of type `B` and are part of [anonymous function syntax](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html). Think of them as placeholders for future values which will be used when the method is invoked.

Let's use `curry` in an example:

```
scala> def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) =
     |   a => b => f(a, b)
curry: [A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C)A => (B => C)
```

We'll pass a function taking two `Int`'s and returning an `Int` and see what happens:

```
scala> curry((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y)
res0: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

We passed a function which takes two parameters, `x` and `y` of type `Int`, and returns the sum of the two values. In return we received a function of type `Function1[Int, Function1[Int, Int]]` which is a function taking a single `Int` value and which returns a `Function1` itself, taking a `Int` value and returning an `Int`.

Now let's what happens when we pass an `Int` value to `res0`:

```
scala> res0(1)
res1: Int => Int = <function1>
```

As expected, invoking `res0` returns a `Function1[Int, Int]`. If we pass another `Int` to `res1`, we'll receive the sum:

```
scala> res1(1)
res3: Int = 2
```

We can also invoke `res0` and pass two parameter lists to get the result:

```
scala> res0(1)(1)
res2: Int = 2
```

In my example, I used `Int` as the type for all parameters for simplicity. But since `curry` is defined for three types `A`, `B` and `C` we can create more complicated functions where the types are different from each other.